# How to compute the gradient of a complicated function with respect to a matrix?

Tags: matrices

I would like to compute the gradient of the following function:

$$F(W)= trace(A \times B) $$

Where:
$$B_{i,j}=\exp(- || W^T (x_i-x_j) ||_2 ) $$

Here, $W$ is a matrix variable, $W \in R^{d \times p}$, $x_i \in R^{d}$ are known vector. In addition, $ || .||_2$ is the L-2 norm.

I know that $ \frac{\partial F }{ \partial W }=\frac{\partial F }{ \partial B } \times \frac{\partial B }{ \partial W }=A \frac{\partial B }{ \partial W }$

However, how to compute $\frac{\partial B }{ \partial W }$. I think this term should be a tensor? Is that correct?

Thanks in advance for your reply.